# How to make SCNNode rotate/spin horizontally

Tags: scenekit, swift4, scnnode, xcode9

I'm trying to make my SCNNode automatically rotate horizontally by itself. This is the code I have so far:

```
box.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.26, y: 0.26, z: 0.26)
box.position = SCNVector3(0.15, 3.85, -3)
```

How do I make this box spin horizontally automatically? And for a plus, is there a way to make it happen with user interaction enabled too? Thanks!

Update: If I didn't sound as clear, this is what I mean: You know when you spin a basketball on your finger and how it's spinning horizontally? That's the effect I'm trying to achieve! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either

- use the `SCNAction` class, e.g. [`SCNAction.rotate(by:around:duration:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction/1523805-rotate). This has the advantage that you can chain multiple animations or repeat them forever,

*Edit:*

```
let action = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 5))
box.runAction(action)
```

- Use [`SCNTransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransaction).

You can change the transform like this

```
let oldTransform = box.transform
let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z angle)
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
box.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotation, oldTransform)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

To use user input you can for example change the angle of the rotation or the duration with a gesture recognizter

Comment: What's axis.x, y, z and angle? When I do SCNMatrix4MakeRotation it sets this as default: angle, x, y, z. I don't know what to put in these values? Do I put the same xyz as my position? And fro angle I do 360 for it to rotate full way around? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question to make it sound more clear. I want the spin effect of a basketball!

Comment: `axis` is the axis you want to rotate around, eg `[0, 1, 0]` or `worldUp`, depending on wether you want to rotate around the local- or global y-axis, and `angle` is the rotation angle in radians, so `.pi * 2` means a full rotation.

Comment: Oh okay, so I could set the axis' to 0 and just change the angle? Or do I set xyz to be the same as my position?

Comment: The axis is the rotation axis, so use (1, 0, 0) if you want to rotate around the x axis, (0,1,0) for the nodes y axis and (0,0,1) for z

Comment: So what does box.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)), forKey: "Changing") do? Nothing happens at all, and when I do this, nothing still happens :( let oldTransform = box.transform
        let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(1, 0, 0, 30)
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 10
        box.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotation, oldTransform)
        SCNTransaction.commit()

Comment: Okay, this code kinda works to what I want it to do. It rotates, but it moves the box around itself, it doesn't leave the box in one spot and just spin it.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI using SceneView updated the accepted answer with some slightly newer syntax.

Works well on iOS14/iOS15

```
    let oldTransform = cubeNode.transform
    let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90), 0, 1, 0)
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
    cubeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(rotation, oldTransform)
    SCNTransaction.commit()
```